# Scheduled task collector not showing in prometheus UI after added in windows exporter

Tags: windows, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I've installed Prometheus version 2.6.0 and Windows exporter version 0.6 in my prod server. I need to monitor the task scheduler event details. I'm using a batch file to run the windows exporter msi file and I've added the respective Scheduled_task collector in that.

Referred official documentation and added

```
msiexec /i C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\windows_exporter.msi ENABLED_COLLECTORS="ad,iis,logon,memory,process,tcp,thermalzone" TEXTFILE_DIR="C:\custom metrics"
```

this command in a batch file to execute the windows exporter msi file.

But after restarting both the windows exporter and prometheus services, I can't able to views the newly added collector in the metrics drop down list or localhost:9090/metrics page.

May I know what is blocking to add a new metrics in prometheus dropdown list

Comment: This is the wrong site to ask about windows service installation and configuration. Consider [su] or [sf]. And don't forget to include actual command used by service in question.